# why doesnt it write to file in exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

**still giving problem**

I have the following code. As long as I am in try { } it writes fine. But when there is an error, it doesn't write to log file. Not sure why

```
 private static void jk(string kName, string path)
        {
            Job job;


            try
            {
             // run some functions here and then write to the file
               StreamWriter LJ = new StreamWriter("C:\\Lob.txt");
            LJ.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXX");

            LJ.Close();   
            }
            catch (InvalidException)
            {
               StreamWriter LJ = new StreamWriter("C:\\Lob.txt");
                LJ.WriteLine("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
                LJ.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Error: ");
                return;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Is `IncalidException` in the actual code, or is that a typo?

Comment: Does it actually create the "Lob.txt" file? Could it be that the StreamWriter cannot actually create the file and it is throwing?

Comment: Is there an exception being thrown inside the catch block? If so, what is the exception? Does the catch block execute successfully and still doesn't write anything to the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the only thing in your try is writing to the stream... and that's the same thing you try to do in the cacth. Why would that work?

Comment: Right. and if yout try fails, writing to that same stream will not work. That's what caused the failure in the first place.

Comment: so should I have a totally new stream in the exception? Not sure if thats what you meant

Comment: Well, yeah... that's kinda what I meant. The stream broke. that's why you are in the catch in the first place. So you can't try to write to the same stream.

Comment: k sure. Will try it and let you know in a few

Comment: still doesnt write to the file. I will update the question with what I have now

Answer (score 3):

The `catch` block executes only when the `try` block throws the exception (which appears to be a typo in the original post).

If the `try` succeeds, the `catch` is never executed.

If the `try` fails, it's because of a problem that must have occurred in writing to the log.  When the `catch` executes, that problem most likely still exists, so the log within the `catch` will fail also.

Comment: try fails because of some other problems but I am trying to log it into the file

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what type `LJ` is, and I certainly have never heard of a `IncalidException`.  I am assuming that you just typed the code into the editor incorrectly.  You should really just paste it in to avoid those types of errors.

Anyway, there are a few options:

1. `LJ.WriteLine` is not throwing an exception.
2. `LJ.WriteLine` is throwing an exception, but not of the same type you are catching (i.e., see if it works when you just `catch { }`).
3. The second call to `LJ.WriteLine` is also throwing an exception and you are catching (and perhaps swallowing) it further up the stack.

Comment: It will if you actually check those three things, specifically #3.  If that code fails once why would you assume that the second time around it will work?  Don't just add more code that is going to fail in your catch block.

Comment: I see where the confusion is...try suppose to run a fucntion and only if that function cant be run then it falls in exception. in try I am just logging to see if it made to that function. And if not, I am logging it in the exception

Answer (score 1):

With your comment:

> try fails because of some other problems but I am trying to log it
>   into the file

I assume that the exception is not thrown by  `LJ.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXX");`

If that's the case, you might just need to flush the StreamWriter. Try declaring LJ in a using block like this:

```
using (StreamWriter LJ = new StreamWriter("C:\\Lob.txt"))
{
    LJ.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXX");

    try
    {
        ...
        LJ.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    }
    catch (InvalidException)
    {
        LJ.WriteLine("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
        Console.WriteLine("Error: ");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling Close should flush the StreamWriter, assuming it gets that far... :)

Comment: I answered before I saw the current edit. The previous version didn't have LJ.Close(). :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to compile this code?

There are two things I see incorrect with the above.

1. It should be InvalidException not IncalidException

   ```
       try
       {
           LJ.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXX");

       }
       catch (InvalidException e)
       {
           LJ.WriteLine("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
           Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
           return;
       }
   ```

Comment: Point 2 is incorrect. If you don't need to reference the exception, catch(InvalidException) { } is perfectly valid.

Comment: Btw, it was not me who gave you the -1.

Comment: No worries, I don't understand the point system yet nor why I should really care, I just enjoy being able help whenever possible.  If it doesn't help then fine, I'd want the correct answers to go to the top because ultimately that's why I use the site.

Comment: The points allow you to brag that you're famous on the Internet. Seriously though, it's just a system for measuring how much you know stuff. People tend to take you more seriously if you have a high enough reputation/points.